# jquery combining multiple selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
alert($('.input-large[name="name"]:parent:parent').html());
```

My html is :

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label for="name" class="control-label">Clinic Name</label>
    <div class="controls">
       <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="input-large" value="">
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm getting null in the alert. How to find the parent of the parent of the input element?

Comment: Should always select by ID whenever possible, so you can skip straight to #name instead of using the class as Zoltan Toth suggested in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
alert( $('#name').parent().parent().html() );
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But can't I combine multiple selectors this way?

Comment: This is the best answer you'll get. Selecting by `#` is a lot more efficient and saves trouble later if you go changing the name or DOM structure.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want this to work for all `input-large[name=name]` elements? See my post below.

Comment: $('#name').parent('.control-group').html() has one less method to chain :)

Comment: @KeirSimmons Yes. I may have multiple elements.

Comment: You can combine multiple selectors if separated by commas. If there are way to many elements - @KeirSimmons's answer is good

Answer (score 1):

For all `input-large[name=name]` elements:

```
$(".input-large[name=name]").each(function(){
    alert($(this).parent().parent().html());
});
```

But then again this will give you an alert for each instance.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the parent().parent() chain as others have done, or just pass the parent selector into .parents() for a cleaner chain, like so:

```
alert( $('#name').parents('.control-group').html() );
```

Comment: whoops, it's parents(), not parent() :). here's a fiddler for ya: http://jsfiddle.net/FjZrF/